# Dark grey bar at the bottom of Chrome in iPad

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, ipados

[image]

The grey bar in Chrome in the image above in iPad OS blocks form fields at the bottom of the screen. I believe it is the auto fill feature Chrome has. I know it is not the shortcuts bar and also predictive text is off.

Is it possible to get rid of this bar to get more space on screen?

Comment: I was about to answer for Safari, but realized you are using Chrome app. As a workaround, can you use the spit keyboard? I’m sure you know you can use a bluetooth keyboard to get back half your screen, but this seems more about using the on-screen keyboard and not just dismissing it entirely.

Comment: Turn your tablet 90 degrees and you get even more space.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove that grey bar because it's an area of the virtual toolbar with additional tools that  will appear like Undo/Redo, Cut, Copy, and Paste. The "up and down arrows" is like hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle between fields on the webpage.  It usually doesn't show unless there are fields to navigate or items in the clipboard.

It appears in Firefox, Safari and Brave browsers as well.

[image]

Comment: This bar is a different one, that is the shortcuts bar, which is already disabled. This bar used to have a password and address icon which went away after I turned off auto fill for those things in chrome.

Comment: @rodrigocf is correct.  If you’ve turned “everything” (shortcuts, predictive, passwords, payments, etc.) off, this bar doesn’t appear in Safari but does appear in Chrome when entering text.